# JMeter: check result after batch processing

Tags: java, tcp, jmeter, batch-processing, load-testing

I am currently trying to measure the performance of a TCP server, and I have the following issue:

The request are ingested by the server, and the server synchronously answers to the tcp client. 
After this first step the data is processed (some kind of batch processing), and written to a table.

With Jmeter, is it possible to implement some kind of probe that will check the creation of the entries in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "table?

- If it is [SQL Table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp), you can use [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler which allows executing arbitrary SQL queries and storing the results into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article for detailed information on configuring JMeter for database connectivity.
- If you are getting some form of table as response data you can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to verify whether expected data is present in the server response or not and conditionally fail the sampler.

Comment: Yes, actually it is send through jms but also stored in a sql table for auditing. I will look into this sampler!